# How to include installer dependencies in dmg/pkg on mac

Tags: macos, installation, dmg, pkgbuild

I have a mac application (Eg. Sample.pkg containing Sample.app) along with  few pkg dependencies (Eg. A.pkg and B.pkg ). Whenever the user runs the `dmg/product` archive bundled with these three packages, `A.pkg` and `B.pkg` has to be run first before `Sample.pkg` is installed.

Is there a way where I can specify this dependency while packaging the mac application, without need the user to manually check and install them in the right order?

Comment: Wow, seeing no answer to this question is so sad!

Comment: I'm trying to solve exactly same issue. 4 years pass on and no answers. @SumalathaAbhishek did you manage find any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

There is a way.
You can add such entry to your `distribution.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
    <title>Application name</title>
    <organization>com.organization</organization>

    ....

    <volume-check>
        <required-bundles description="Some message which UI Installer doesn't show :(">

            <!-- bundle 1 -->
            <bundle id="com.organization.app1" path="Applications/App1.app" />

            <!-- bundle 2 -->
            <bundle id="com.organization.app2" path="Applications/App2.app" />
        </required-bundles>
    </volume-check>

    ....
</installer-gui-script>
```

This is documented here [(required-bundles)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW38).

Some examples can be [found on github](https://github.com/search?q=required-bundles%20extension%3Axml).

### Disadvantage

There is some bug in Apple Installer, `required-bundles description` says:

> #### Attributes
>
> ```
> |----------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
> | Attribute name |       Type       |                       Description                          |
> |----------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
> |                |                  | _Optional._ Values: `true` (default) to require all of     |
> |     `all`      |     Boolean      | the specified bundles, or `false` to require at least one  |
> |                |                  | of them.                                                   |
> |----------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
> |  `description` |   String,        | _Optional._ A description of the required bundles,         |
> |                | localization key | displayed to the user if the requirement is not met.       |
> |----------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
> ```

So the message from `description` should be shown, but I can't see it anywhere, so user can be confused why he is unable to install application.

It just warns: `You can't install <your application> here, <your application> do not allow it.` (sorry translation from my localization back to English).

### Alternative

I've seen some installation package which was running custom script form [installation-check](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW12) invoking it from installation JavaScript, using `system.run('script_name')`.